# Django views.PasswordResetView send email not html type

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to reset my password But email doesn't looks like a html
urls.py

```
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_form.html',
        email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url='/account/password_reset_done'
    ), name='password_reset'),
```

password_reset_email.html

```
<p>您收到这封邮件是因为您正在重置密码，如果非本人操作请勿略</p>
<p>请点击下面网站设置一个新密码:</p>
<a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'account:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}"></a>
<p>用户名:{{ user.get_username }}</p>
<p>感谢使用我们的网站</p>
<p>晶晨羽毛球协会</p>
```

setting.py

```
# 将发送的邮件直接显示在控制台
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# smpt服务地址
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.qq.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
# 发送邮件的邮箱
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx33928@qq.com'
# 在邮箱中设置的客户端授权密码
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxgorrbecd'
# 收件人看到的发件人
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xxx3928@qq.com'
SERVER_EMAIL ='xxx3928@qq.com'
```

myemail

```
<p>您收到这封邮件是因为您正在重置密码，如果非本人操作请勿略</p>
<p>请点击下面网站设置一个新密码:</p>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password_reset_confirm/MQ/5i4-0dfc61d517145c2857dd/"></a>
<p>用户名:coco</p>
<p>感谢使用我们的网站</p>
<p>晶晨羽毛球协会</p>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from .views import UserListView, RegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='account/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),

    url(r'^password_change/$', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_change_form.html',
        success_url='/account/password_change_done/'
    ), name='password_change'),

    url(r'^password_change_done/$', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_change_done.html',
    ), name='password_change_done'),

    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_form.html',
        html_email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url='/account/password_reset_done'
    ), name='password_reset'),

    url(r'^password_reset_done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),

    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_confirm.html',
        success_url='/account/password_reset_complete'
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'password_reset_complete/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_complete.html'
    ), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

error
Error during template rendering
In template /home/coco/.virtualenvs/badmintion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 6

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

It looks like a txt. Label is not userful .
Where is my problem .How can I fix it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `email_template_name` parameter in a [**`PasswordResetView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) is used for a *text* email. You should make use of the `html_email_template_name` parameter (so with a `html_` prefix):

```
url(
    r'^password_reset/$',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_form.html',
        html_email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html',
        email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url='/account/password_reset_done'
    ), name='password_reset'
),
```

Comment: In this way.I got an error about password_reset_confirm,
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @赵小甲: that is because the template renderer aims to parse the `{% url 'account:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`, but apparently that view does not exists. Can you edit the question and show the full `urls.py`?

Comment: Sure My urls.py     url(r'^password_reset_done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),

Comment: path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_confirm.html',
        success_url='/account/password_reset_complete'
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),

Comment: url(r'password_reset_complete/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='account/password_reset_complete.html'
    ), name='password_reset_complete'),

Comment: It too long for one comment .I an new for stackoverflow .Are these info enough ?

Comment: @赵小甲: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62861973/edit) the question. Does it have an `app_name = ...`?

Comment: No .  I am not define it

Comment: @赵小甲: then likely it should be `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` so without the `account:`

Comment: But it's fine when i use email_template_name='account/password_reset_email.html .Not html_xxxx.It's able find password_reset_confirm.And i got email form django . I will try without account .

Comment: My main urls  url(r'^account/', include(('account.urls', 'account'), namespace='account')), .Maybe I should add account:

Comment: I double check the error info .It seem look like not load my password_reset_email.html .Django using the default one and in default one there is no account : . Error Path : In template /home/coco/.virtualenvs/badmintion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 6 .I am still not fix it .

Comment: @赵小甲: but do you still have a `email_template_name`? You should add both, since an email has a text part, and an optional html part.

Comment: @赵小甲: you can thus for example let both refer to the same template (or better, make a dedicated one for text). This is useful since not all mail clients use HTML (think for example about `mutt`).

Comment: Tks. There is no error output When I use html_email_temaplate_name and email_template_name.